# Javascript Basic: Search and Highlight

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to highlight a word within a div when page will be loaded. My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function highlight(container,what,spanClass) {
    var content = container.innerHTML,
        pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)(' + what + ')([^<.]*)','g'),
        replaceWith = '$1<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$2</span>$3',
        highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);
    return (container.innerHTML = highlighted) !== content;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="highlight(document.getElementById('hello'),'florida','highlight');">
<div id="hello"> Florida florida orlando orlando</div>
Florida Texus florida 
</body>

</html>
```

And nothing is happening in FF/Chrome/IE. I need your advice to fix this.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wLnb4/1/

Comment: regexing HTML is not recommended - see what happens if you search for "hello" in your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this code you use only works if there are some HTML tags around your elements.

It will work in a more general case, for example if you change your div to

```
<div id="hello"><p> Florida florida orlando orlanodo</p></div>
```

To make it work with your HTML you may use a simpler regex :

```
new RegExp('(' + what + ')','g')
```

and a different replacement :

```
replaceWith = '<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$1</span>'
```

You could also have just changed your regex to make the groups optional :

```
pattern = new RegExp('(>[^<.]*)?(' + what + ')([^<.]*)?','g'),
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsbin.com/okoyik/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is highlight the word `florida` if it is separated then try

```
function highlight(container,what,spanClass) {
    var content = container.innerHTML,
        pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + what + ')\\b','g'),
        replaceWith = '<span ' + ( spanClass ? 'class="' + spanClass + '"' : '' ) + '">$1</span>',
        highlighted = content.replace(pattern,replaceWith);

    return (container.innerHTML = highlighted) !== content;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wLnb4/)